# SharedPreferences can't/won't delete data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to delete shared preferences data using a alert dialog within my app, so:

settings shared prefs:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0);
        startLat = Double.longBitsToDouble(settings.getLong("startLat", 0));
        endLat = Double.longBitsToDouble(settings.getLong("endLat", 0));
```

deleting data method:

```
public void discardLocation() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0).edit();
        settings.clear();
        settings.commit();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location Discarded!", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: Do you get your "Location Discarded" Toast?  Where is the code in which you set the preference, and the code in which you determine that it *has not* been cleared?

Comment: Yes it shows up when I hit "yes". I set the preference in onCreate and then save the data in onStop. Check edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actual Answer:**

I figured out why `SharedPreferences` wasn't working for me.

Basically I never set my `SharedPreferences`variable globally!

**Work around:**

Haven't figured out why I can't delete my data using `SharedPreferences`

However, there is a work around. If you're storing any sort of numbers (int, double) you can just set them back to what they were originally were within the `deleteCoordinates()` method.

For example in my code, I'm using coordinates. The coordinates default setting is 0:

```
double startLat = 0;
double endLat = 0;
```

So after the coordinates have been set to another value. (Coordinates will never be 0) you just set them back to 0 in `deleteCoordinates()`.

```
startLat = 0;
endLat = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main activity should declare your prefs context...

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.default_values, false);
```

Then you get an editor and commit the changes. It should just work.

2 types of commit exist and you should review the API.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mactivity).edit();
ed.putString("default_parse_user_oid", id);
ed.putString("default_parse_user_token", token);

ed.apply();
```